# How to change from exact color to exact color in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: colors, photoshop

In Adobe Photoshop, if you created a line with a specified hexadecimal color value, how can you duplicate that layer/object and change it to a different specified hexadecimal value without having to manually adjust the hue and saturation (which even then is almost impossible)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd say copy the object, click on the foreground color selection, enter new hex value and it should change the color to the one you need.

Comment: i'd have to create line as a shape layer and then stroke it with the colors later. dur, can't believe i missed that. awesome man, thanks. you're a life saver! :)